# How does the variable times works out in this specific line of code

Tags: javascript

I currently trying to learn how to animation in javascript works and I got a little bit stuck. The blog that I am reading is https://javascript.info/js-animation and this pice of code just drives me crazy.

```js
let prev = performance.now();
let times = 0;

requestAnimationFrame(function measure(time) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeEnd",
    Math.floor(time - prev) + " "
  );
  
  prev = time;

  if (times++ < 10) requestAnimationFrame(measure);
})
```

I cannot uderstand what the variable times is all about, why he use time in the Math.floor method and why prev = time. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `times` is just a counter (up to 10). The `time` argument is the timestamp passed to `requestAnimationFrame`. Its value is explained in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame#parameters)

Comment: Ok. So, to check if I understood correctly, when the function measure is over it checks if times is less than 10, if it is, it executes the requestAnimationFrame again until times get bigger than 10 and it stops. But what about the value of time when it calculates time - prev and why after the calculation prev = times?

Comment: Exactly! See the answer below for further explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `times`

Here, `times` is used as a counter to call the `requestAnimationFrame` function 10 times:

#### What this line does:

```
if (times++ < 10) requestAnimationFrame(measure);
```

- Check if `times` is less than 10
- If so, call `requestAnimationFrame`
- Increment `times`

---

## `time = prev`

`time` holds the timestamp at the function call, with very high accuracy. This is then assigned to `prev`, which is presumably used to hold the timestamp during the previous function call

The reason for this is explained in the next section

---

## `Math.floor(time - prev)`

Here, `time` holds the time during the current function call with very high precision, and `prev` the time during the previous function call.

If you subtract `prev` from `time`, You'll get the amount of time elapsed between the two.

The `Math.floor` function then rounds this down to an integer, after which it is inserted into the body using the `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML` function.

Comment: What's interesting is that (at least on my browser), the first frame executes _before_ the `performance.now()` timestamp. In any case, I'd be more inclined to assign the initial `prev` in the first frame

Comment: @Phil Strangely enough, it happens to me too, causing the first number to be negative.